# Fastest way to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase and retrieving the data "books" from my firebase database. Then adding books titles as an option to a select tag.

The problem is that the data take time to charge in the select list ! so when i charge the page the select list is empty and after 4 to 5 seconds it displays with the options

**this is my code**

```
var db = firebase.database()
    var ref = db.ref(); 
    // get Titles 
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('titres/');
    databaseRef.once('value' , function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    const list = document.getElementById('favoris');
    [childSnapshot].forEach(item => {
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = item.key;   
      option.text=item.val().nom; 
     list.appendChild(option);
    });

      });
    });
```

is there a better a way to do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React build a component to handle the data and build your list and here's how I'd request the data from Firebase:

```
let titresDB = firebase.database().ref('titres')
titresDB.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  let data = []
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    data.push({
      _key: childSnapshot.key,
      ...childSnapshot.val()
    })
  })
  // then do something with the data
  // in React you could setState
  this.setState({ data })
})
```

List component:

```
    <ul>
      {this.state.data.map((book) => {
        return (
          <li key={book._key}>
            <h3>{book.title}</h3>
            <p>{book.rating}</p>
            <p>{book.description}</p>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
```